# Error running config for nvim-lsp- installer

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

Aparece un error al intentar instalar nvim-LSP-installer y nvim-ispconfig:

```
packer.nvim: Error running config for nvim-lsp-installer:
...nvim-lsp-installer/lua/nvim-lsp-installer/middleware.lua:1: module 'lspconfig.util' not found:
^Ino field package.preload['lspconfig.util']
^Ino file './lspconfig/util.lua'
^Ino file '/home/oriyia/.tmp/neovim/.deps/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/lspconfig/util.lua'
^Ino file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lspconfig/util.lua'
^Ino file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lspconfig/util/init.lua'
^Ino file '/home/oriyia/.tmp/neovim/.deps/usr/share/lua/5.1/lspconfig/util.lua'
^Ino file '/home/oriyia/.tmp/neovim/.deps/usr/share/lua/5.1/lspconfig/util/init.lua'
^Ino file '/home/oriyia/.cache/nvim/packer_hererocks/2.1.0beta3/share/lua/5.1/lspconfig/util.lua'
^Ino file '/home/oriyia/.cache/nvim/packer_hererocks/2.1.0beta3/share/lua/5.1/lspconfig/util/init.lua'
^Ino file '/home/oriyia/.cache/nvim/packer_hererocks/2.1.0-beta3/lib/luarocks/rocks5.1/lspconfig/util.lua'
^Ino file '/home/oriyia/.cache/nvim/packer_hererocks/2.1.0-beta3/lib/luarocks/rocks5.1/lspconfig/util/init.lua'
^Ino file './lspconfig/util.so'
^Ino file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lspconfig/util.so'
^Ino file '/home/oriyia/.tmp/neovim/.deps/usr/lib/lua/5.1/lspconfig/util.so'
^Ino file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
^Ino file '/home/oriyia/.cache/nvim/packer_hererocks/2.1.0-beta3/lib/lua/5.1/lspconfig/util.so'
^Ino file './lspconfig.so'
^Ino file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lspconfig.so'
^Ino file '/home/oriyia/.tmp/neovim/.deps/usr/lib/lua/5.1/lspconfig.so'
^Ino file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so
```

Neovim v0.7.0 is installed in `/opt/nvim/`. Packer installed according to the instructions.

Directory with configs:

```
-init.lua
-lua
   -plagins.lua
   -options.lua
   -keymaps.lua
```

Plugins.lua contains:

```
return require('packer').startup(function()
    -- Packer can manage itself
    use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
    -- tokyonight theme
    -- onedark
    use 'navarasu/onedark.nvim'

    -- nvim-lsp-installer, nvim-lspconfig
    use {
        {
            "williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer",
            config = function ()
                require("nvim-lsp-installer").setup{}
            end
        },
        {
            "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
            after = "nvim-lsp-installer",
            config = function()
                local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
                lspconfig.pyright.setup {}
            end
        }
    }
end)
```

I tried to find at least something similar to the problem, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `:PackerSync`. That solved it for me.
It does

```
mv ~/.local/share/nvim/site ~/.local/share/nvim/site.bak
```